# Matlab GUI,how to tell both of the variables exist in a uicontrol

Tags: matlab, user-interface, exists

```
function pushbutton8_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
EndDate = handles.EndDate
StartDate = handles.StartDate
if exist('EndDate')
    if exist('StartDate')
        if(datenum(EndDate,'yyyy/mm/dd')<datenum(StartDate,'yyyy/mm/dd'))
            StartDateEarlierThanEndDate
        else
            Correct
        end
    else
        makesureboth
    end
end
```

`EndDate` and `StartDate` will be chosen by users. If `EndDate` is earlier than `StartDate`, a GUI saying "StartDate must be earlier than EndDate" will come out. If a user only chooses `EndDate` or `StartDate`, a GUI saying "Make sure you choose both StartDate and EndDate" will come out. `EndDate` and `StartDate` come from another `uicontrol`.

If a user does not select both the `StartDate` and `EndDate`, it gives an error `Reference to non-existent field 'EndDate'` or `Reference to non-existent field 'StartDate'` . I know the reason of this error, but I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: `isfield` together with logical short circuiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking whether `handles.EndDate` exists before doing `EndDate=handles.EndDate`, which will fail if `EndDate` does not exist. Maybe something along the lines of the following:

```
function pushbutton8_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if ~isfield(handles,'EndDate') || ~isfield(handles,'StartDate') 
    % if either EndDate or StartDate do not exist, call makesureboth
    makesureboth
else % both variables exist
    if(datenum(handles.EndDate,'yyyy/mm/dd')<datenum(handles.StartDate,'yyyy/mm/dd'))
        StartDateEarlierThanEndDate
    else
        Correct
    end
end
```

Comment: I was just about to say... `exist` might not like that.  ;) +1 now!

Comment: I didn't realise `exist` didn't work on struct's until I saw your comment! Not sure why it shouldn't though?

Comment: When you pass something to `exist`, it is a string, which means it would have to parse out the name of the struct before the "." and then run `isfield` on its own.  They probably didn't implement that because it would be a can of worms when you start thinking about nested structs or non-scalar structs.  Also, it might be slightly more error prone to pass the whole thing: if it came back false would it mean the struct didn't exist or the field or either?

Comment: you solved my problem, thats a perfect answer! thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @David's answer, you could also save the trouble of checking for the existence of a field by checking directly in the uicontrol used to enter StartDate and EndDate (I guess it's an edit box?).

If it's possible, you could add a verification step at the beginning of the pushbutton's callback and check whether the entered dates are valid, and if so move on. That might save you some trouble later as you make sure the user inputs correct values in the first place. That does not answer directly your question but it was way too long for a comment :)